# Does Ghostscript absolutely need root access on Linux?

Tags: linux, ghostscript

I made a program trying to see how many color pages are on an uploaded PDF file, using Ghostscript. Now, it worked perfectly on my local environment, but I can't put the site online, as the web hosting service I use tells me that any application that needs root access cannot be installed on the server. Is it the case with Ghostscript, and if so, is there any other way I can use it ?

I'm new to all this, and I know now I should have asked the web hosting service first thing, but I'd really like to not have to put my work in the bin over this !

Answer (score 1):

No Ghostscript doesn't require root privileges and I've no idea why they would claim it does. Also, I would strongly urge you to review the AGPL license.

Comment: Are you sure Ghostscript is correctly installed on the server?

Comment: Well I extracted a file called "gs-950-linux-x86_64", without extension, which I put on the server, but don't know what to do from here. Ghostscript's docs says to access ./configure, and use "make" from there, but I don't know how I can do that, given that there seems to be no ./configure folder.

Comment: That sounds like (incorrect) instructions for building Ghostscript. If you want to build Ghostscritp from source you navigate to the ghostpdl directory and run ./autogen.sh and then make. If you don't have autogen.sh then you don't have a compelte Ghostscript source tree. That said, the filename you quote suggests it is a binary release, not a source archive, in which case you don't need to build it, its an executable. All you need to do is run it.

Comment: That's it, running it with "gs" did it. I was pretty sure I tried it before, but apparently not. Thank you all for your answers, it helped me a lot !